# How to enable multi touch gestures

Tags: touchpad, gesture

I'm trying to set up three finger swipes to cycle between workspaces with no success. I installed touchegg and got some config files but couldn't get it working.

After I run touchegg I get this message and then nothing happens.

```
Try to make a multitouch gesture. If everything goes well the information about the gesture must appear 
[+] Avaliable gesture: 
     Name ->  Flick 
[+] Avaliable gesture: 
     Name ->  Drag 
[+] Avaliable gesture: 
     Name ->  Pinch 
[+] Avaliable gesture: 
     Name ->  Rotate 
[+] Avaliable gesture: 
     Name ->  Tap 
[+] Avaliable gesture: 
     Name ->  Touch
```

I've changed the config file to set up gestures I know work in my hardware (such as two finger scroll) but again, nothing happens.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Are you on Loki? touchegg does not work on it, unfortunately. Also, I think there is not something like it that works on Loki, but I am not sure

Comment: Yes, I'm on Loki. :( Shame. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: I remember posting about 16.04 or 16.10 gnome about touchegg.  I was told it is not updated and does not work.   I have never seen it work.

Answer (score 1):

Touchegg does not work in Loki.  However, I also posted a question that was not voted on or answered..   One needs to use Libinput gestures..  you can follow the link below and if you do everything right you can get workspaces to work out of the box.  anything else is my question.. how?

[Multi-Touch Gestures for eOS config file for Libinput OS](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/10432/multi-touch-gestures-for-eos-config-file-for-libinput-os)

Answer (score 1):

Credits : [Bulletmark](https://github.com/bulletmark/libinput-gestures) and [Neal Fennimore](https://neal.codes/blog/adding-mac-like-touch-gestures-to-elementary-os)

Follow Neil Fennomore's solution given on his page.

However, installing libinput-gesture, install xdotools and wmctrl

> apt install xdotools wmctrl

[Bulletmark's page] says :
"The default gestures are in /etc/libinput-gestures.conf. If you want to create your own custom gestures then copy that file to ~/.config/libinput-gestures.conf and edit it." So I had to additionally execute (and I use 'Gedit') :

> cp /etc/libinput-gestures.conf ~/.config/

and

> gedit ~/.config/libinput-gestures.conf.

and then append required lines for my gestures to the file. For eg. :

> gesture swipe up 3 xdotool key super+Up

More gesture commands could be found on Neal's page.