# Multi-Touch Gestures for eOS config file for Libinput OS

Tags: touchpad

How to configure the config file for libinput config
I want the apple gestures to work on elementary.
I am able to change workspaces by swipe up and down.  but that is just about it.
For those of you who do not know about this, please see

https://github.com/bulletmark/libinput-gestures

and this link here

https://web.apeconsulting.co.uk/wordpress/adrian/touch-me-touch-me-say-that-you-love-me/

There are some gnome commands..

Here is the file below:

```
# Configuration file for libinput-gestures.
#
# The default configuration file exists at /etc/libinput-gestures.conf
# but a user can create a personal custom configuration file at
# ~/.config/libinput-gestures.conf.
#
# Lines starting with '#' and blank lines are ignored. Currently
# "gesture" and "device" configuration keywords are supported as
# described below. The keyword can optionally be appended with a ":" (to
# maintain compatibility with original format configuration files).
#
# Each gesture line has 3 [or 4] arguments:
#
# action motion [finger_count] command
#
# where action and motion is either:
#     swipe up
#     swipe down
#     swipe left
#     swipe right
#     pinch in
#     pinch out
#
# command is the remainder of the line and is any valid shell command +
# arguments.
#
# finger_count is a single numeric digit and is optional (and is
# typically 3 or 4). If specified then the command is executed when
# exactly that number of fingers is used in the gesture. If not
# specified then the command is executed when that gesture is executed
# with any number of fingers. Gesture lines specified with finger_count
# have priority over the same gesture specified without any
# finger_count.
#
# Typically command will be xdotool, or wmctrl. See "man xdotool" for
# the many things you can action with that tool. Note that unfortunately
# xdotool does not work with native Wayland clients.
#
# Note the default is an "internal" command that uses wmctrl to switch
# workspaces and, unlike xdotool, works on both Xorg and Wayland (via
# XWayland). It also can be configured for vertical and horizontal
# switching over tabular workspaces, as per the example below. You can
# also add "-w" to the internal command to allow wrapping workspaces.

# Move to next workspace (works for GNOME/KDE/etc on Wayland and Xorg)
gesture swipe up    _internal ws_up
#gesture swipe up   xdotool key super+Page_Down

# Move to prev workspace (works for GNOME/KDE/etc on Wayland and Xorg)
gesture swipe down  _internal ws_down
#gesture swipe down xdotool key super+Page_Up

# Browser go forward (works only for Xorg, and Xwayland clients)
gesture swipe left  xdotool key alt+Right

# Browser go back (works only for Xorg, and Xwayland clients)
gesture swipe right xdotool key alt+Left

# Example of 8 static workspaces, e.g. using KDE virtual-desktops,
# arranged in 2 rows of 4 across using swipe up/down/left/right to
# navigate in fixed planes. Must match how you have configured your
# virtual desktops.
#gesture swipe up   _internal --col=2 ws_up
#gesture swipe down _internal --col=2 ws_down
#gesture swipe left _internal --row=4 ws_up
#gesture swipe right    _internal --row=4 ws_down

# GNOME SHELL open/close overview (works for GNOME on Wayland and Xorg)
gesture pinch in dbus-send --session --type=method_call --dest=org.gnome.Shell /org/gnome/Shell org.gnome.Shell.Eval string:'Main.overview.toggle();'

gesture pinch out dbus-send --session --type=method_call --dest=org.gnome.Shell /org/gnome/Shell org.gnome.Shell.Eval string:'Main.overview.toggle();'

# This application normally determines your touchpad device
# automatically. Some users may have multiple touchpads but by default
# we use only the first one found. However, you can choose to specify
# the explicit device name to use. Run libinput-list-devices to work out
# the name of your device (from the "Device:" field). Then add a device
# line specifying that name, e.g:
#
#device DLL0665:01 06CB:76AD Touchpad
#
# Or you can choose to use ALL touchpad devices by setting the device
# name to "all". This reduces performance slightly so only set this if
# you need to.
#
#device all
```

Comment: Do you think there is any way to get also the pinch to zoom gestures to work with Browsers?

Comment: I could only get workspace switching.  That wast the whole point of posting this question.  I also want gestures that are useful

Answer (score 10):

I managed to make it work with:

```
git clone http://github.com/bulletmark/libinput-gestures
cd libinput-gestures
sudo make install
sudo apt install libinput-tools xdotool
sudo gpasswd -a $USER input
libinput-gestures-setup autostart
```

And create the file '~/.config/libinput-gestures.conf' with the next contents:

```
gesture swipe up xdotool key super+Left    
gesture swipe down xdotool key super+Right
```

Then log out and log in again.

So you will change desktop with 3 fingers 'up' and 'down' swipe.

It also works with 'swipe left' and 'swipe right' but it is very clumsy on my macbook so I prefer the 'up/down' movement.

It is not as fast and comfortable as OSX, but something similar.

Comment: Thanks.. I was also able to get it to work.  Up and down changes desktops right out of the box without any mods.  The question was how to get more gestures.